# Things which are need for run ember without ember-cli?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I am new to emberjs. Can anyone tell how to create ember pages without using ember-cli?

Comment: Can you provide some context on why? Are you talking about serving production assets?

Answer (score 3):

This has been [deprecated](https://emberjs.github.io/rfcs/0331-deprecate-globals-resolver.html) and is no longer supported.

While theoretically possible you basically would need to rebuild all the stuff that `ember-cli` does on your own.